# html+css background-image in windows phone

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

So, I have a problem :
I'm developing an app on windows phone ( html + javascript ) and have an image that should be a background .
The image is 480px 800px .
My html

```
<meta name="Viewport" content= "height= device-height; user-scaleable=no; initial-scale=1.0" />

 <body>
   <div class="container">
   </div>
 </body>
```

My css

```
.container {
background-image:url(../img/fundo1.jpg); /* 480px x 800px */
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

}

In the emulator I do not see the whole image only a part of it.

any sugestion?
Thansk for all

Comment: Have you tried changing your position to "fixed"?

Comment: Hi Elizion. Yes, I tried, but not yet. I change code to background: url(../img/fundo1.jpg) no-rep'eat center center fixed;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}